# Installing and Configuring grub to use as a bootloader

Tags: linux-mint, windows, grub2, dual-boot

I needed to install a Linux partition on my SSD that contained Windows 10 and I did just that, using a bootable UEFI usb. The distribution I used is Mint 18.3 Sylvia.

During installation, I partitioned the free space as 4 logical partitions:

- EFI with bootable tag on
- /
- swap
- /home

And chose the EFI partition created to install the bootloader, following online reccomendations.

Currently the system boots automatically into Mint, and as far as I can tell there is no grub installed at all. I thought it always installed grub and I would just need to update it to find the windows partition.

I'd love to  be able to boot into the windows partition, and I believe installing grub to use as a bootloader is the solution, as it would be able to find both Mint and Windows in the system. Is this the correct way to proceed?

Any help and insight is really welcome, I never had to install or configure grub, so I am not even sure it would fix my problem.

p.s. the lsblk as it stands:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb      8:16   0 111,8G  0 disk 
├─sdb4   8:20   0     1K  0 part 
├─sdb2   8:18   0  62,7G  0 part 
├─sdb7   8:23   0   6,5G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sdb5   8:21   0   714M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sdb3   8:19   0 541,3M  0 part 
├─sdb1   8:17   0 337,3M  0 part 
├─sdb8   8:24   0  22,4G  0 part /home
└─sdb6   8:22   0  18,6G  0 part /
```

Comment: Grub IS installed because it's the default boot loader for any Debian/Ubuntu based distros and an ESP (EFI system partition) should be there already, why did you made a new one? It seems you need to learn about UEFI and how to dual boot with Windows. Use this a reference: https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi

Comment: Ah I managed to access grub2 indeed, it is simply I never had it to be hidden before (GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0). Windows is not showing on grub screen now though, even after a update-grub.

Comment: There's no Windows partition in your list. Better check again if it's really there, the Disks app/tool is easier to use than commands. I'm afraid you deleted Windows somehow.

Comment: Isn't it sdb2 ?

Comment: It is sdb2 indeed. With sdb1 being the recovery partition windows create on install if I remember correctly.

Comment: I can actually mount the partition and see all my windows files no problems... still can't get it to show on grub.

Comment: You could try: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 1):

Run the command `df -kh` in terminal to see how much free space you have free in sdb5. If you have more than 200-300MB free, continue:

If the `grub-efi-amd64` (the EFI grub) package is installed, then just reinstall grub. (To check if it is installed, run `sudo dpkg -s grub-efi-amd64`, status should be `installed ok installed`)

Then run `sudo grub-install /dev/sdb` to install it to your hard drive.

`sudo os-prober` - to detect other OS installed on your computer.

`sudo update-grub` - to update your GRUB configuration.

You should be ready to go.

EDIT: If  you've somehow formatted the Windows EFI system partition and the Windows bootmanager is gone, this will not help. You'll have to boot a Windows recovery USB, however, that might be dangerous for your Linux system.